# Moon illumination and phaseangle or direction

Tags: php, astronomy, drawing2d

1. Calculating the phase of the Moon is pretty straightforward.  I'm not asking that.  The moon actually changes its phase-angle and illumination because of librations and other factors.  (see here for the moon phases for 2011: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f_21N3wcX8)
2. Meeus in Astronomical Algorithms (pgs. 98-99 Ch. 14 and pgs. 345-357, chs. 48-50), gives formulae for the phase, illumination, phase-angle and and the parallactic angle to show the position and illumination of the moon.  The problem I have is implementation in php.  How to translate angles in order to achieve the relevant filled-in arc, together with a dark circle to create the appearance of the moon correctly as it would appear in the night sky.
3. I am aware of imagearc ( resource $image , int $cx , int $cy , int $width , int $height , int $start , int $end , int $color) which obviously creates the arc, with the relevant angle.

To create the horns, or the illusion of a crescent, can one superimpose two arcs on top of each other?  The other question is can this be used in tandem with a blur, shadow and actual moon image to make it more realistic?  Or am I better off implementing this in CSS?  Are there any implementations in code that draws the actual moon as determined by the Phase and Paralletic angles?

Comment: You're asking to programmatically draw a moon using [tag:gd]…? Please clarify what you already have and what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: programmatically draw a moon with the data from meeus: that is angle, illumination, position.  The question is the best way of implementing it, and can you superimpose two images ontop of each other in imagearc?